# How to install Method::Signatures on perl-5.32.0?

Tags: perl

I want to upgrade to `perl v5.32` but I can not because my app uses `Method::Signatures` module which depend on `Devel::Declare` which does not work at `perl v5.32` =(

Probably I need to search for alternatives of `Method::Signatures` to do same checks as is was with it:

```perl
method _mtemporal_get_checks(
    DateTime :$as_at!,
         Int :$query! where { ( 0 <= $_ ) && ($_ <= 0xff) },
         Str :$source_alias!,
         Str :$dimension!
) {
...
}

method check_euid_egid(
    Maybe[HashRef]  :$security_configuration,
    Bool            :$try_to_set
) {
...
}
```

But how to install `Method::Signatures` on perl-5.32.0?
I see that testers [did that](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Method-Signatures+20170211). Tests are passed.

But locally I get next error:

```
Building Devel-Declare-0.006019
cp lib/Devel/Declare/Context/Simple.pm blib/lib/Devel/Declare/Context/Simple.pm
cp lib/Devel/Declare.pm blib/lib/Devel/Declare.pm
cp lib/Devel/Declare/MethodInstaller/Simple.pm blib/lib/Devel/Declare/MethodInstaller/Simple.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Declare ()
chmod 644 "Declare.bs"
"/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Declare.bs blib/arch/auto/Devel/Declare/Declare.bs 644
"/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl" "/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/ExtUtils/typemap'  Declare.xs > Declare.xsc
mv Declare.xsc Declare.c
cc -c  -I/opt/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux/B/Hooks/OP/Check/Install -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.006019\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.006019\" -fPIC "-I/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/x86_64-linux/CORE"   Declare.c
In file included from Declare.xs:7:0:
stolen_chunk_of_toke.c: In function 'S_scan_word':
stolen_chunk_of_toke.c:449:58: error: macro "isALNUM_utf8" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
  else if (UTF && UTF8_IS_START(*s) && isALNUM_utf8((U8*)s)) {
                                                          ^
stolen_chunk_of_toke.c:449:39: error: 'isALNUM_utf8' undeclared (first use in this function)
  else if (UTF && UTF8_IS_START(*s) && isALNUM_utf8((U8*)s)) {
                                       ^
stolen_chunk_of_toke.c:449:39: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
stolen_chunk_of_toke.c: In function 'S_scan_ident':
stolen_chunk_of_toke.c:935:62: error: macro "isALNUM_utf8" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
      else if (UTF && UTF8_IS_START(*s) && isALNUM_utf8((U8*)s)) {
                                                              ^
stolen_chunk_of_toke.c:935:43: error: 'isALNUM_utf8' undeclared (first use in this function)
      else if (UTF && UTF8_IS_START(*s) && isALNUM_utf8((U8*)s)) {
                                           ^
make: *** [Declare.o] Error 1
-> FAIL Installing Devel::Declare failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1603559352.13/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Comment: I would like to know that too. On my list of modules to look into are Kavorka, Type::Params and Function::Parameters. I'm not a fan of the builtin signatures because the functionality is quite limited.

Comment: heh, the `Devel::Declare` module deprecated itself years ago, see [WARNING](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Declare#WARNING) in its docs.  So trying to get things to work with it isn't a good way to go and I'd suggest that you figure out other tools.  Same advice to @BarneySchmale

Answer (score 4):

The Signature feature has been around since perl v5.20.
[https://perldoc.perl.org/feature#The-'signatures'-feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature#The-%27signatures%27-feature)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.20;
use feature 'signatures';
no warnings "experimental::signatures";

say add_things(10 , 20);


sub add_things ( $x , $y )
{
    return $x+$y;
}
```

Comment: Tip: `use feature 'signatures'; no warnings "experimental::signatures";` can be reduced to `use experimental qw( signatures );`

Comment: While they are flagged experimental, they are considered relatively stable. I think they would have been enabled by default in Perl 7 if it wasn't for the conflict with Method::Signatures